Snowflake sequence issue
I'm trying to create a sequence into Snowflake for a table ID, I need it to increase 1 by 1 (1,2,3,4,...), how ever when I create it and try sequence.nextval it increases (1,101,201,301...) and I don't know why.
I'm using the next code to create the sequence (I'm using sysadmin and the correct database)
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SEQ_AUTHOR_UID
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
    COMMENT= 'Use this to fill in AUTHOR_UID';

Also I tried with:
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_AUTHOR_UID
    START = 1
    INCREMENT = 1
    COMMENT = 'Use this to fill in AUTHOR_UID';

enter image description here

Hi - this is clearly covered in the documentation here : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences. Can you clarify why you need contiguous numbers?

This is a non issue like @NickW says. It's working as intended. I would assume this is a result of the documentation not being read and it looking... odd. Because it does, until you know why. There are answers listed that explains this, please select one of them or clarify what the issue is. This is working as intended.

When you create a new sequence or a new auto-incremented column, you can specify the ORDER or NOORDER parameter to indicate whether or not the sequence can generate new values in increasing order.
ORDER specifies that the values generated for a sequence or auto-incremented column are in increasing order (or, if the interval is a negative value, in decreasing order).
For example, if a sequence or auto-incremented column has START 1 INCREMENT 2, the generated values might be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.
NOORDER specifies that the values are not guaranteed to be in increasing order.
For example, if a sequence has START 1 INCREMENT 2, the generated values might be 1, 3, 101, 5, 103, etc.
NOORDER can improve performance when multiple insert operations need to be performed concurrently (for example, when multiple clients are executing multiple INSERT statements).
Default: The NOORDER_SEQUENCE_AS_DEFAULT parameter determines which property is set by default.
Please review the below documentation for more information:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/bcr-bundles/2024_01/bcr-1483
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence#optional-parameters
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#noorder-sequence-as-default
To get the sequence order, use order parameter.
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SEQ_AUTHOR_UID
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
order;
select SEQ_AUTHOR_UID.nextval;


Hi @sasank_sharma - I don't think your answer addresses the issue of a sequence not generating contiguous numbers, which is what the question is about, so I'm not sure it's actually an answer. However, feel free to explain how it does address the question if you want to

Please read the below behavior change:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/bcr-bundles/2024_01/bcr-1483
We should be able to repro with the customer question.
To get the sequence order, use order parameter.
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SEQ_AUTHOR_UID
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
order;
select SEQ_AUTHOR_UID.nextval;

I don't believe this affects the fundamental way Snowflake generates sequences - but happy to be proved wrong. At the top of this page https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences and also on the CREATE SEQUENCES page it states that "Snowflake does not guarantee generating sequence numbers without gaps. The generated numbers are not necessarily contiguous.". My understanding of the question is that they want contiguous numbers and this is not possible with sequences

As per NickW's pointing to the documents:

Important
Snowflake does not guarantee generating sequence numbers without gaps. The generated numbers are not necessarily contiguous.

A sequence is only guaranteed to be larger than the prior value retrived, this is called Monotonic function which preserves order.
This means you can tell that if an Sequence is < it came before, and thus also if > it came after the row in question. To have gapless numbers you will need to use ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY sequence_id).
This has the problem that you have to do this on read every time.
You can use an UPDATE to write the whole table to have stable numbers, but this has the problem of if any row is deleted now you have gaps. This might be why you want gapless numbers, but if this is the case it makes more sense to use a Stream to monitor the table. OR if you need a longer life gap detection use a seconardy table, with a insert on INSERT or DELETE logic, depending on the balance of write change/read work you expect for the table.

This needs to be marked as the correct answer, documentation within snowflake clearly states that this is working as intended.
